# How to *not* save a mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose field X.
I query it and update its data.

In a certain condition, it has to be duplicated, and only the new copy has to be saved to the DB with the new data (the original has to remain the same as it was before the query).

but somehow, mongoose saves the original document even though I didnt ask it to with a .save() command.

```
X.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec(function (err, original) {

       original.name = 'newName';

       if(condition){
            var copy = new X(original);
            copy.isNew = true;
            copy._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

            X.collection.insert(copy, callback(){})

        }else{

           original.save();

        }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Show your schema, please.

Comment: What are the possible value for _condition_ ?

Comment: Some strings from the x's value. They are not bring touched

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose may be doing some magic when you run a constructor with an existing Mongoose object as argument.

First I'd try to run the constructor without the _id in the first place instead of changing it later. Example with lodash:

```
const copy = new X(_.omit(original, ['_id']));
```

Second I'd try passing only needed fields explicitly:

```
const { field1, field3, field3 } = original;
const copy = new X({ field1, field2, field3 });
```

Or with lodash:

```
const copy = new X(_.pick(original, ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']));
```

And thrird if all else fails I'd try to serialize and deserialize it as JSON to make sure that all the magic is gone:

```
const { field1, field3, field3 } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
const copy = new X({ field1, field2, field3 });
```

or:

```
const copy = new X(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_.pick(original, ['f1', 'f2'])));
```

Make sure to run the JSON opertaions in a try/catch block to handle exceptions, or use a module like `tryjson`.

Comment: Hi thanks, I think that that wasn't the problem - the problem is that mongoose saves the original object to the DB, when it doesn't have the save() command. I tried all your suggestions, and the problem stands still